# Programming Phoenix Wolfram Alpha Service Returning `[]` instead of results tuple

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm working through the Programming Phoenix book and my Wolfram service isn't working as expected.

When I run the following command in `iex -S mix`:

```
Rumbl.InfoSys.compute("what is the meaning of life?")
```

It returns:

```
[]
```

The expected value is something like this:

```
[%Rumbl.InfoSys.Result{​backend:​ %Rumbl.User{...}, ​score:​ 95, 
​text:​ ​"​​42\n(according to the book The Hitchhiker"​, ​url:​ nil}]
```

Here's the contents of `lib/rumbl/info_sys/wolfram.ex`

```
defmodule Rumbl.InfoSys.Wolfram do
  import SweetXml
  alias Rumbl.InfoSys.Result

  def start_link(query, query_ref, owner, limit) do
    Task.start_link(__MODULE__, :fetch, [query, query_ref, owner, limit])
  end

  def fetch(query_str, query_ref, owner, _limit) do
    query_str
    |> fetch_xml()
    |> xpath(~x"/queryresult/pod[contains(@title, 'Result') or
                                 contains(@title, 'Definitions')]
                            /subpod/plaintext/text()")
    |> send_results(query_ref, owner)
  end

  defp send_results(nil, query_ref, owner) do
    send(owner, {:results, query_ref, []})
  end

  defp send_results(answer, query_ref, owner) do
    results = [%Result{backend: "wolfram", score: 95, text: to_string(answer)}]
    send(owner, {:results, query_ref, results})
  end

  defp fetch_xml(query_str) do
    {:ok, {_, _, body}} = :httpc.request(
      String.to_char_list("http://api.wolframalpha.com/v2/query" <>
        "?appid=#{app_id()}" <>
        "&input={URI.encode(query_str)}&format=plaintext"))
    body
  end

  defp app_id, do: Application.get_env(:rumbl, :wolfram)[:app_id]
end
```

...and `lib/rumbl/info_sys/supervisor.ex`

```
defmodule Rumbl.InfoSys.Supervisor do
  use Supervisor

  def start_link() do
    Supervisor.start_link(__MODULE__, [], name: __MODULE__)
  end

  def init(_opts) do
    children = [
      worker(Rumbl.InfoSys, [], restart: :temporary)
    ]

    supervise children, strategy: :simple_one_for_one
  end
end
```

Why am I not getting the correct return value in `iex`? Any help is appreciated - please let me know if you'd like to see any other files.

Comment: Does it work when you send the same query with Curl or Wget?

Comment: how do I make a request with curl or wget?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you did not use WolframID/Email address instead of AppID? That was my mistake, having no experience with Wolfram. For the appid you have to as wolfram. See Obtaining an AppID http://products.wolframalpha.com/api/documentation.html#1

Good luck, Stefan Houtzager.

Answer (score 0):

`{URI.encode(query_str)}` should be `#{URI.encode(query_str)}`

Comment: This is more of a comment.